# Refresh/clear listview

Tags: android, listview

I trying to get list view that created by extending  base adapter to refresh, clear the list  items  refresh. I  used the notifyDataSetChanged method. But not refreshing the data, into the base adapter I parsing an array. thank you

```
          Myadapter baseadapter = new Myadapter(context,array) ;
           setListAdapter(baseadapter);
               baseadapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: IMHO there is nothing wrong with your code. Sorry, I don't understand the question.

Comment: Please add the adapter code, the problem is there. (specially the method getView )

Answer (score 3):

I did not understand your question completely, assuming that you are trying to refresh your list view but you are not getting it refreshed.

Well, assuming array to be an ArrayList, to get the effect of refreshing ,all you have to do is,

```
array.clear();
```

Then, populate the arrayList with new data and invoke,

```
baseadapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

I repeat, since your question was not clear i have assumed you are trying to get your listView refreshed.